# Como enviar uma variável python para a area de transferência do sistema operacional?

Tags: python, linux, windows

Estou implementando um gerador de textos específicos e ele me retorna uma string no terminal; gostaria que automaticamente essa string fosse copiada para a area de transferência.

Estou usando windows mas gostaria de uma solução mais generalista, ou 3 soluções, que ai eu posso fazer a seleção automática dado o SO.

Comment: Copiar para Área de Trabalho ou para Área de Transferencia? São coisas diferentes.

Comment: Desculpe realmente errei o termo, área de transferência que eu queria dizer

Comment: No repositório do PIP tem diversas libs de terceiros que irão resolver, pesquise por [clipboard](https://pypi.org/search/?q=clipboard)

Answer (score 1):

Procurando por conteúdo em inglês encontrei o pyperclip, uma biblioteca que pode ser instalada via pip.

Instalação pyperclip:

```
pip install pyperclip
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
import pyperclip
variavel = "isso é uma string de teste"
pyperclip.copy(variavel)
```